# .htaccess SEO friendly URLs - redirect to page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

i am looking at .htaccess files and have my site now redirect all links to SEO friendly links

e.g

```
 http://example.com/index.php?page=1 to
 http://example.com/home/1/
```

by using the following code

```
 RewriteRule ^home/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

but when i got to the page

```
 http://www.example.com/home/
```

i get a 404 error....

How can i get it so that when /home/ is accessed it automatically redirects to /home/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^home/?$ http://www.yourdomain.com/home/1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^home/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

R=301 means that redirect is permanent according to [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301)

Comment: it kinda works but it redirecting with the full path of the file

http://192.168.0.6/C:/Program%20Files/VertrigoServ/www/website/Home/1